# What (()?) and ()? means in swift?

Tags: swift, option-type

```
var aa: (()?) = (john.residence?.address = someAddress)
var bb: ()? = john.residence?.printNumberOfRooms()
```

Is this to distinguish whether only nil?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`()` is the empty tuple type (same as `Void`).

`()?` is the optional version of that.

`(()?)` is a tuple containing the type `()?` so reduces to just `()?`

Comment: Single-value tuples like `(1)`, `("a")`, and `(()?)` reduce to the value itself (`1`, `"a"`, and `()?`, respectively).

Comment: @pcperini That seems to match observed behavior, but do you have an actual reference on it?

Comment: @David: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH31-XID_1093 "If there is only one element inside the parentheses, the type is simply the type of that element. For example, the type of (Int) is Int, not (Int)."